# Question about ending and motivation in Oculus

Tags: plot-explanation, oculus

In the movie [Oculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oculus_(film)), why did the Mirror let Tim live?

It could have easily orchestrated some sort of murder-suicide. Or did the Mirror simply not care for killing everyone that interacted with it?

Comment: Was Tim truly alive???

Comment: @MissouriSpartan you mean he could have been hallucinating the whole thing?

Comment: It’s revealed throughout the film that the Mirror was messing with people’s minds.....some deaths were real, others weren’t......or were they? That’s what’s so amazing about this film is it leaves you wondering what was real and what wasn’t....

Answer (score 1):

The mirror probably had more fun creating the same scenario for Tim when he was a child: Being taken to a mental institution while blaming the mirror for everything.